# Given an integer, how many ways can you divide into unequal portions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms, dynamic-programming

I have been thinking about this problem for a while but have been unable to formalize a complete answer.

Given an integer $n \geq 3$, how many different sets can you sum the integer elements in the set to equal n ?

**Constraints:**

1) Each set must contain at least 2 elements.

2) All elements in a set must sum to $n$ (all elements must be greater than 0).

3) Normal set rules apply: No elements in a set can be repeated, and Order doesn't matter

**Examples:**

when n = 3 the only possible set is {1, 2} so the answer would be 1.

when n = 4 the only possible set is {1, 3} so the answer would be 1.

when n = 5 there are two sets {1, 4}, {2, 3} so the answer would be 2.

This is meant to be a programming question. I think the answer could be computed as a math equation, or at least a dynamic programming approach. My goal is for the run time to not exceed O(n), however O(1) would be great. If you want to provide code python like syntax would be fine.

Comment: And for $n=6$ you have $\{1,5\},\{2,4\},\{1,2,3\}$ for $3$

Comment: As a first step, you can bound the size of your set by finding the least $k$ for which $1+2+\cdots +k >n$ (simple quadratic to solve).

Comment: @lulu Yes I could do something like that, and enumerate all sets with a bounded size, then step down (-1) the bounded size and repeat until a bounded size of 2. However, that method would get very messy and would be very inefficient because I would be wasting time computing the actual sets, when I only want the number of possible sets.

Answer (score 2):

This is one less than [OEIS A000009](http://oeis.org/A000009), which begins $1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 32, 38, 46, 54, 64, 76, 89, 104, 122, 142, 165, 192, 222, 256, 296, 340, 390, 448, 512, 585, 668, 760, 864, 982, 1113, 1260, 1426, 1610, 1816, 2048, 2304, 2590, 2910, 3264, 3658, 4097, 4582, 5120, 5718, 6378$.  The one less comes because you prohibit the partition of $n$ into $\{n\}$ which the OEIS sequence allows.  No simple formula is given, but one of the asymptotic ones is $$a(n) \approx \exp(\pi\sqrt{n/3})/(4\cdot 3^{1/4}\cdot n^{3/4}) \cdot (1 + (\pi/(48\sqrt3) - (3\sqrt3)/(8\pi))/\sqrt n + (\pi^2/13824 - 5/128 - 45/(128\pi^2))/n)$$

Comment: Lets say n had an upper bound of 200. Would the equation be able to handle that as a floor or a ceiling for all integers between 3 <= n <= 200?

Comment: Could you also explain the "one less" comment in more detail?

Comment: For $6$ they also count $\{6\}$, getting four choices.  You don't count that, so get $3$.  The first $1$ in the sequence corresponds to $n=0$ and the $4$ corresponds to $n=6$.

Comment: I see, the only thing I don't understand now is how to compute the next number in the sequence.

Comment: I tried the approximation but it was severely off .

Comment: @JakeStephens:  I may have miscopied it, or it may be off for small $n$.  Some of these asymptotic approximations take a long time to get close.

Comment: Can you explain how to compute the next number in the sequence?

Comment: No.  There are lots of formulas in the OEIS link.  The one that looks most useful is a(n) = P(n)-P(n-2)-P(n-4)+P(n-10)+P(n-14)+...+(-1)^m P(n-2p_m)+..., where P(n) is the partition function (A000041) and p_m =m(3m-1)/2 is the m-th generalized pentagonal number (A001318). - Jerome Malenfant, Feb 16 2011

Answer (score -1):

Let $N_i(n)$ give the number sets of size $i$. You want $\sum_{i=2}^\infty N_i(n)$.

Clearly $N_2(n) = \lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$.

To compute $N_3(n)$, we're going to try to find the three-member set from least to greatest. If the least member is a $1$, then the other members are all at least $2$; we can subtract $1$ from the other $2$ members, and we need two unequal numbers adding to $n-3$; there are $N_2(n-3)$ such possibilities. Similarly, if the least member is $2$, there are $N_2(n-6)$ possibilities; etc. So $N_3(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor} N_2(n-3i)$.

Similarly, $N_4(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\rfloor} N_3(n-4i)$

You can try to devise some computation method based on these relations; however, I'm not sure it will be so computationally efficient.

Comment: Better/not worse/amounts to the same is to recursively create a table for $S(n,k)$ the number of subsets $\subset \mathbb N_{\leq k}$ with sum $n$. For the recursion, distinguish according to the largest element. «[Dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)» to use a fancy word.